# top menu is on top of side menu, error in css

Tags: css

I have this problem! I am trying to add two menus top and side.
But top menu is coming at the top of side menu! Can anyone fix the css?

[this is my fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/ez51f7Lv/)

I tried to give `#leftPanel` `position:fixed` but it doesn't have any affects.

Comment: Please reduce your code to a minimum, that shows the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add

```
#leftPanel{
 width: 20%;
 float: left;
 background-color: blue;
 margin-top:52px;
}
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8ydretrw/)